# C# Autocomplete textbox in windowsforms application throws error "System.AccessViolationException"

Tags: c#, windows, forms, autocomplete

currently I am working on a program to implement a backup function. Therefore I try to select computer names via the Active Directory and display them as a suggestion under a text box.
This also works so far, but now and then it comes to the problem that he does not show any suggestions but the error "System.AccessViolationException". I also did not find a solution through research. I can only imagine that he tries to read the autocomplete list while it is being filled again.

Hope someone has a advice for me!

Thank you very much!

```
 //Textbox Declaration
 this.textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
 this.textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
 this.textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = backup.pc_names_return();

 //Textbox changed function
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)    
 {    
    if (textBox1.Text.Length > 4)    
    {    
       try    
       {    
           backup.get_pc_names(textBox1.Text);    
       }    
       catch    
       {    
       }    
    }    
 }

private AutoCompleteStringCollection auto_values = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

 //Autocomplete PC Names
 public void get_pc_names(string input)
 {
    auto_values.Clear();
    if (input.Length > 0)
       {
          DirectoryEntry de = new 
          DirectoryEntry(ad_connection_string);
          DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
          SearchResultCollection src;
          ds.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=Computer) 
          (objectClass=Computer)(Name=" + input + "*))";
          src = ds.FindAll();
          if (src.Count > 0)
          {
             int counter = 0;
             foreach (SearchResult member in src)
             {
                string temp = member.GetDirectoryEntry().Name;
                temp = temp.Replace("CN=", "");
                auto_values.Add(temp);
                counter++;
                if (counter == 5)
                {
                   break;
                }
            }
         }
      }
  }



 //Return autocomplete
 public AutoCompleteStringCollection pc_names_return()
 {
    return auto_values;
 }
```